# Concatenating dictionaries with different keys into Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, one-hot-encoding

Let's say I have two dictionaries with shared and unshared keys:

```
d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
d2 = {'b': 4, 'c': 3}
```

How would I concatenate them into a dataframe that's akin to one-hot enoding?

```
a   b   c
1   2   
    4   3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the same result as what you are showing...

```
pd.DataFrame([d1, d2], dtype=object).fillna('')

   a  b  c
0  1  2   
1     4  3
```

If you want to fill missing values with zero and keep a `int` `dtype`...

```
pd.concat(dict(enumerate(map(pd.Series, [d1, d2])))).unstack(fill_value=0)

   a  b  c
0  1  2  0
1  0  4  3
```

Or as pointed out by OP in comments

```
pd.DataFrame([d1, d2], dtype=object).fillna(0).astype(int)

   a  b  c
0  1  2  0
1  0  4  3
```

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't this for for ex2? pd.DataFrame([d1, d2], dtype=object).fillna(0)

Comment: @leonyin yes, but I'd add `astype(int)`... `pd.DataFrame([d1, d2], dtype=object).fillna(0).astype(int)`